# How to restrict a user access to delete opportunity

Tags: userrecordaccess

here is my simple but a little clumsy scenario I have 4 users under a profile. My requirement is user1 should be able to delete his/her Opportunities but not user2,user3,user4. How can I achieve this, please suggest me guys.

Answer (score 0):

You can create `Permission set` and assign to user 1 provide access to delete his/her opportunities

for more information refer this link : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/perm_sets_overview.htm

Comment: For this I have to deselect "Modify All" for Opportunity from their profile?

Comment: @Laxman, Are you using custom profile or standard one ?

Comment: custom profile Nihar.

Comment: If you have created permission set and user2, user3 are still able to delete then yes you can deselect it and give it a try.

Comment: you need to deselect modify all in profile level & gave access to delete in permission set

Comment: Hello Nihar/Pavan If I want user2,user3 and user4 should delete their records and not user1 records(however user1 should be able to delete his/her records and user1 should not be able to delete remaining users records), how can we achieve this?. And user1 should be able to view remaining users records.

Comment: @Laxman You just need to assign this permission set to user1 and remove assignment from user2, user3 and user4

Comment: Looks like something is not correct here, created a permission set and assigned to user1, but user1 is able to delete remaining users records(opportunities).

Comment: First create a profile like x with opportunity access would create edit viewall & provide to all users.So, all users now able to viewall records edit there own records.Now create a permission set in object settings for opportunity give delete acess and assign to user1.

Comment: Done accordingly, and user1 is able to delete user2,user3,user4 opportunities yet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, With the help of **Permission Set**.

### [Assign Permission Sets to a Single User](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=perm_sets_assigning.htm&type=0)

- From Setup, enter Users in the Quick Find box, then select Users.
- Select a user.
- In the Permission Set Assignments related list, click Edit Assignments.
  -To assign a permission set, select it under Available Permission Sets and click Add. To remove a permission set assignment, select it under Enabled Permission Sets and click Remove.
- Click Save.

### [Assign a Permission Set to Multiple Users](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=perm_sets_mass_assign.htm&type=0)

Assign a permission set to one or more users from any permission set page

- Select the permission set that you want to assign to users.
- Click Manage Assignments and then Add Assignments.
- Select the checkboxes next to the names of the users you want assigned to the permission set, and click Assign.

Comment: Nitesh, For this I have to deselect "Modify All" for Opportunity from their profile?